# BigQuery concat returns null concatenating empty strings

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, null, concatenation

I have a simple table (loaded from a view on top of files) with Countries and Zip codes in BigQuery.
For some strange reason when both Country and Zip code are empty ... concat returns null instead of an empty string... to pass the "is null" test. :(

```
select * 
from `TEST_business`.`zip` as z
where concat(country, zip) is null
```

Returns one line as shown in below image:
[image: One result where concat() is null]

BUT if I run it with a separator

```
select * 
from `TEST_business`.`zip` as z
where concat(country, '-', zip) is null
```

it returns no lines, as no country or zip are effectively null, as below image shows:
[image: concat() with separator returns no rows]

Lastly, let's be sure there are no NULL in any of the two columns

```
select * 
from `TEST_business`.`zip` as z
where country is null or   zip is null
```

Image shows that BQ itself could not find any row with contry or zip equal to null:
[image: Check for null country or zip returns no rows]

So I am baffled at why this could happen, it looks like a bug to me... or I miss the logic of some strange empty string to null conversion from BQ.

To complement the info: I know that the data coming into the zip table sometimes has null values for country, so country is coalesced into an empty string when loading the zip table (that currently recreated at every run)... and this behaviour has not happened before despite being long time that we run this same test after every load... and we have the same rows that have a null country that get coalesced into an empty string since months.

Comment: i was not able to reproduce your issue . anyway - just in case - check this post - [Any CONCAT() variation that tolerates NULL values?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43421671/5221944)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I think the behaviour was coming from Files having null and being passed through a view that coalesce them to an empty string on null, that is then saved into the table, but somehow the coalesce is lost in the concat. I was unable to reproduce from straight SQL values entered into a query, only from that table coming from the view coming from files; that's why I took screenshots. –
It was also strange that adding a literal string like '-' changes the output from null, to non null...

Comment: I was neither able to reproduce it. For example `with dt as (select '' as country, '' as zip)
select * from dt where
concat(country, zip) =""` is returning the row while `with dt as (select '' as country, '' as zip)
select * from dt where
concat(country, zip) is null` has no results. Yes, maybe you're right, it can be related to how the file is being parsed

Comment: @issuela I was not able to reproduce the issue myself with "fabricated data". That is why I was baffled and why I took so many screenshots. I think it was something related with the specific file.